# React Native ListView get visible rows

Tags: listview, react-native

I'm building a chat app. I need an ability to mark messages which are viewed currently in list view and user sees it as read. How can I find out is this row currently visible for the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I've found RN-component which can help to get information about component's visibility.
https://github.com/yamill/react-native-inviewport

Comment: A small note about this project though, is that it polls for the position of that component every X milliseconds. Something to consider when making an app with battery consumption in mind.

Comment: @terry : I also want to do the same thing and i tried to implement this library but couldnt implement it gives error at library's index.js 11th line which is onChange: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired, that it doesnt not found React.PropTypes.func. Can u please send me code i am looking for it from many days. Thanks